# Firebase crashlytics script in iOS(2021) not working via Testflight

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, run-script

I am trying to integrate firebase crashlytics into iOS app.
During integration I added run script to upload crashes automatically.

I connected my iPhone_XR to Xcode and ran in release mode. Then I force crashed.I repeated it several times. After few hours of waiting I was able to see the crashes. Confirming that this is working as expected I archived and released this build(DEV) to testflight via xcode.

I did the same force crashed after installing via testflight but this time its not working... Most of the people suggested to upload manually but I am afraid I can't do that as I don't have access to client application(PROD) and also maintaining the crashes report manually is a tidious process to me

Please help me what exactly is happening with Firebase crashlytics. I checked many blogs and github issues for understanding. Most of them are saying to upload manually dSYM files.

[image: Crashlytics Run script]

Note: GoogleServices file is inside some folder so I gave the path of that in script. I tried to add directly without any sub-folders also but issue still persists.

[image: Crashlytics Report]

4-MAR crashes are from my phone which are crashed during testing.

I am supposed to receive some crashes on 5-MAR which are crashed via Testflight but it's saying missing dSYM files

Please help with this issue. I am not unable to find proper solution from past 2 months

Comment: For TestFlight you will need to download the dSYMs from Apple and manually upload them: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios#expandable-1 here are the instructions for running the "upload-symbols" tool: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios#upload-dsyms

Comment: I would like to do it automatically and i explained why in the question.

Comment: The script to upload the dSYMs automatically "FirebaseCrashlytics/run" will work only if you will use the dSYMs generated by Xcode. But, when using TestFlight or if you have BitCode enabled and release the app in the App Store, then you must download them from the App Store Connect. The dSYMs are not crashes, these are files that will be use to deobfuscate the actual crash report. This is needed once per build and not per crash.

Comment: This post explains how to do those steps programmatically using Fastlane, although is a bit old so I'm not sure if everything works in the same way, but that would be the basic idea: https://krausefx.com/blog/download-dsym-symbolication-files-from-itunes-connect-for-bitcode-ios-apps

Answer (score 0):

Try this script:

```
${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run
${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp $PROJECT/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

Also, Firebase recently updated their SDK.